# DateTime Picker Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy creando un widget para la seleccion de una fecha en flutter

El mismo es un TextField el cual le quito el control al usuario y cuando se presiona sobre el despliga un calendario que al seleccionar una fecha establece el valor como texto del TextField

La cuestion es que si selecciono una fecha, funciona perfectamente pone el texto de la fecha como valor del TextField pero a pasar el foco a otro widget el Textfield pierde el valor.

Este es mi widget de Fecha

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_house/ui/shared/globals.dart';

class DateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  DateWidget({@required this.controller, this.hintText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: this.controller,
      cursorColor: Global.mediumBlue,
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 100),
                lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1))
            .then((value) => controller.text =
                '${value.day.toString()}/${value.month.toString()}/${value.year.toString()}');
      },
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Global.mediumBlue,
        fontSize: 14.0,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Global.mediumBlue),
        focusColor: Global.mediumBlue,
        filled: true,
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Global.mediumBlue),
        ),
        labelText: hintText == null ? "DD/MM/YYYY" : hintText,
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
          size: 18,
          color: Global.mediumBlue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envuelve el TextField en un GestureDetector y reemplaza el onTap asi:

```
     GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                    firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 100),
                    lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1))
                .then((value) {
              controller.text =
                  '${value.day.toString()}/${value.month.toString()}/${value.year.toString()}';
            });
          },
          child: TextField(
            controller: this.controller,
            enabled: false,
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Al suplantar el codigo no me inserta el texto en el TextField y me deja poder escribir en el TextField. Mi idea es que el textfield no sea editable por el usuario pero si le pongo enabled en false entonces no me sirve para reconocer el Tap sobre el

Comment: En ese caso, pon la propiedad enabled en false, y envuelve ese TextField en un GestureDetector y en la propiedad onTap del GestureDetector, colocas el código que abre el calendario, sin el FocusNode o FocusScope.

Comment: Al hacerlo igualmente pierde el valor del TextField